# Adding frames or divs above Unity3D-Facebook-SDK Canvas Application

Tags: facebook, authentication, unity-game-engine, facebook-login, facebook-unity-sdk

I would like to create a canvas page which loads the Unity3D application instead of directly linking to the *.unity3D file. The reason being I would like to have links to other games, pages, etcetera inside a div above and underneath my application.

The problem is when I don't use the Facebooks Unity integration method (directly linking to a Unity Binary URL) the login button doesn't work within my application.

So my problem is: is their a way to add frames or divs above the Unity3D application?

Thanks in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgX0Z.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can do what you need. For my game, I needed to display ads via Appnext, but as you mentioned, unity3d renders ON TOP OF EVERYTHING, no matter what in the canvas page.

So, as a solution, I injected some javascript code in my canvas page, and whenever I wanted to show an ad, I would call the javascript function that made the canvas of the game 1px x 1px, show the ad, and when the ad was closed/clicked, restore the size of the game.

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you please mark it as a correct answer then :D ?